# Setting up Wordpress blog for React site

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, amazon-web-services, server-side-rendering

I have a web app built with react js. I want to setup Wordpress blog to **domain.com/blog**  path.

Right now I am using Apache to host the site (hosted using Elastic Beanstalk on AWS) and we soon plan to implement Server Side Rendering thus will end up using Node + Express.

What should be the right approach to implement it? Should I handle it at Load Balancer end or need to tweak React routes in order to implement this?

Edit - I have Application load balancer for domain.com (web app). Also I have a different EC2 instance for Wordpress blog that I need to access from domain.com/blog . Now my pain point is that domain.com/blog will be a valid route for React Router but I need to point domain.com/blog to that EC2 instance hosting a Wordpress blog.

Comment: So your domain.com is webapp and domain.com/blog will be your wordpress server. If so both will run in 2 differetn server. 
What are you load Balancing?

Comment: @MyTwoCents Application load balancer is for domain.com (web app). Now I have a different EC2 instance for Wordpress blog that I need to access from domain.com/blog . Now my pain point is that domain.com/blog will be a valid route for React Router but I need to point domain.com/blog to that EC2 instance hosting Wordpress blog.

Comment: One way would be add a subdomain like this blog.domain.com and configure it to Wordpress EC2 instance.
In this way you dont need to do any change in App side.

Comment: @MyTwoCents Although that option is available but we don't want to go that route due to SEO purposes. We have to go with domain.com/blog anyhow.

Comment: In that case you can redirect to WP Server (assuming its Domain name is wp.com) but URL will change from domain.com/blog to wp.com
You can't keep url as domain.com/blog and load content of wp.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a [react starter you can download from here](https://github.com/iamtimsmith/using-react-with-wordpress-demo.git). The solution is also in there on another branch. You can download the files, run yarn or npm install (whichever you prefer) and then yarn start or npm run start. You will see our simple page, but will notice that there isn't any content. Lets get started and add some content.

**Install Necessary Packages**

If we open up the package.json file, we can see that I have already included react, react-dom, and bulma to build our front-end. Before we can go further with our react js app, we need to add a few more packages.

We can add [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) which is a package that allows us to make http requests from our application without any hassle. [React-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) can be used to create routes which means that we can switch pages or components without a browser refresh. To install these two packages, we can use the following code in our terminal:

```
npm install axios react-router
```

**Add React Router to App.js file**

Now that we have our new packages installed, we need to set up react-router in our app.js file to tell our browser what should be displayed when different paths are entered into the address bar. To start, we need to import the pieces we need from react-router at the top of the file. At the bottom of the imports, add the following code:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Now that we have imported react-router, we can use those components to set up routes. Our current app.js file looks something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Header from "./components/header";

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Header />
    <section className="section container content">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </section>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

To add a router to our app.js component, we need to wrap the outermost  in a  component so we can set up our application's routes. Then we can replace our  tag with these two routes:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={PostList} />
<Route path="/:slug" component={PostView} />
```

**Let's break this down:**

Our first route tells reactjs to show a component called PostList when a user visits the home route (http://localhost:1234). The exact attribute means that it needs to match this route exactly, which means that if we have anything after that it will not go to this route.

The second route will show a component called PostView when a user visits a wildcard route. The :slug denotes that any string after the slash will be a different route in our application. In our case, this string or slug (since that's what we named it) will be the slug for the TechCrunch blog post. Our app.js file should now look like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./components/header";
import PostList from "./components/postList";
import PostView from "./components/postView";

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Header />
      <section className="section container content">
        <Route exact path="/" component={PostList} />
        <Route path="/:slug" component={PostView} />
      </section>
    </div>
  </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Next we need to create the `PostList` and `PostView` components and import them into the `app.js` component.

Comment: domain.com/blog must point to a different server hosting a Wordpress blog.